# Scrapy Pagination XHR 400 Bad Request

Tags: python, pagination, scrapy, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to fetch all url from `https://www.magzter.com/magazines/listAllIssues/503`

In one set, Page show 12 magzines and scroll paginate and proceed with next 12 magazines

After Debugging, Upcoming request are as follows

```
https://www.magzter.com/magazines/listAllIssues/503/12
https://www.magzter.com/magazines/listAllIssues/503/24
```

[image: xml Request]

But get request to `https://www.magzter.com/magazines/listAllIssues/503/12` through

```
400 Bad Request
```

Is there any implementation of this scenario in scrapy please provide a sample script.

or any other library which stimulate infinite scrolling and work with scrapy framework

Comment: Check that the POST (if POST is even the right method) request you're sending to the server is formatted correctly; has all the necessary keys; and such things. I also suggest looking a bit more into 400 requests in general.

Comment: @WiggyA. It is a get method

Comment: Then why are you sending a POST request?

Comment: @WiggyA. it was typo, I did get request but the error is still same

Comment: Post your scraper code

Comment: @TarunLalwani https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154356/discussion-between-rahul-sharma-and-tarun-lalwani come here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the request is a AJAX request and not sending it `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header makes it a 400 bad request. There is no way to send headers directly from shell command line, so you need to launch shell and type commands to fetch the request with headers

```
$ scrapy shell --nolog

>>> from scrapy import Request
>>> req = Request("https://www.magzter.com/magazines/listAllIssues/146/12", headers = {"X-Requested-With" : "XMLHttpRequest"})
>>> fetch(req)
>>> response.body
b'\r\n\t<div class="mag-wrap">\r\n    \t<h3></h3>\r\n    \t<ul class="mag-list main-magz">\r\n            <li>\r\n                        <div class="cover-wrap"><a href="https://www.magzter.com/IN/EFY-Enterprises-Pvt-Ltd/Electronics-For-You/Science/183025" onclick="ga(
```